# Tag support on Posts for custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

On my custom theme, my posts (Not custom posts, the default ones) don't have tag support. When I try and add it using register_taxonomy() it messes up, and I cannot see tag pages. Any help here would be really appreciated. I thought tag support should be there automatically.

I tried using register_taxonomy.